# Многопоточность в Django

Tags: python, django

В интеренете куче разрозненной информации многопоточности в Django. Некоторые говорят, что она держится на костылях, некоторые утверждают, что ее вообще нет... Есть ли в Django стандартные механизмы для многопоточности и как вообще с этим обстоят дела ?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, всеми современными веб-серверами многопоточность не предусмотрена в принципе, ибо нафиг не нужно (есть асинхронщина, но это немного другая история). Вы лучше расскажите, зачем оно вам, а мы вам расскажем, как это делать правильнее всего

Comment: Саму джангу обычно запускают в несколько процессов, а не потоков. Для асинхронных задач используют celery. Опишите задачу, пока слишком абстрактно

Comment: @andreymal Apache и nginx это не современные сервера? Многопоточность модель более распространенная.

Comment: @Alex78191 апач не современный и у него обычно многопроцессность вместо многопоточности, nginx асинхронный и может работать даже с одним воркером без доп. потоков, и его воркеры это опять же процессы а не потоки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как сказали выше, сервер запускает джангу в нужное количество процессов.
Сама джанга написана в синхронном стиле, и по словам разработчиков на асинхронный лад её переписать невозможно.

А многопоточность средствами джанги не предусмотрена. Тем не менее никто не мешает открывать нужные потоки и процессы средствами самого python.